# startActivityForResult returns to wrong activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to open a PDF file in my app.

I do so by using this code, in a child activity:

```
        Intent addPDFIntent = new Intent();
        addPDFIntent.setType("*/*");
        addPDFIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        addPDFIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(addPDFIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

This works in that it allows me to go to my file explorer and pick a file. However, once I pick that file, the program goes to my MainActivity's (the parent) OnActivityResult with a resultCode of 0 and and a requestCode of 0, with data == null.

What I expect it to do (which it isn't doing) is return to the activity which called the intent's onActivityResult() method. Which I have implemented (with no body other than a Log telling me if it was entered) -- but it never enters this method. It returns to my MainActivity with no data.

Can someone please help me understand why this is so?

EDIT2: Also, this second activity is started with StartActivityForResult but I never call finish() on this in my addPDF process.

EDIT: By request here's the offending class.

```
public class PasteActivity extends Activity {
public static final String KEY_PASTE = "paste";
public static final String KEY_TEXT = "text";
public static final String TAG = "SPREE";
static final int REQUEST_CODE = 2;
private EditText mPasteField;
private Button mDoneButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_paste);
    Log.i("SPREE", "onCreated");

    mPasteField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pasteField);
    mDoneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.doneButton);
    textShared();
    final Intent returnToMain = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    returnToMain.putExtra(KEY_PASTE, mPasteField.getText().toString()
            .trim());
    returnToMain.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT);
    mDoneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                startActivity(returnToMain);
            } else {                
            Intent data = new Intent();
            data.putExtra(KEY_PASTE, mPasteField.getText().toString()
                    .trim());
            setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
            finish();
            }
        }
    });

    Bundle received = getIntent().getExtras();
    String receievedString = received.getString(MainActivity.KEY_TO_READ);
    mPasteField.setText(receievedString);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // maintains typed text
        mPasteField.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_TEXT));
    }

}

void textShared() {
    Log.i("SREE", "textShared()");
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
            handleSendText(intent);
        }
    }
}

void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
    String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    if (sharedText != null)
        mPasteField.setText(sharedText);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState
            .putString(KEY_TEXT, mPasteField.getText().toString());

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.paste, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.clearText:
        mPasteField.setText("");
        return true;
    case R.id.pasteText:
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        if (clipboard.hasPrimaryClip()) {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            String pasteText = clipboard.getText().toString();
            mPasteField.setText(pasteText);
        } else
            Toast.makeText(this, "Nothing to paste.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        return true;
    case R.id.addPDF:
        Intent addPDFIntent = new Intent();
        addPDFIntent.setType("*/*");
        addPDFIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        addPDFIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(addPDFIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
        return true;
    default:
        return true;
    }

}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    textShared();
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.i(TAG, "WORKS!");


}
```

Comment: Is this where you calling above method, a fragment or activity?

Comment: I call above method in Activity B. And when I pick a file. It goes to Activity A (Main) and calls onActivityResult there with no data, and bad resultCode.

Comment: You implementing onActivityResult() in this activity B?

Comment: Can you post your entire class

Comment: Clay -- added it now. Entire source code available here if necessary: https://github.com/doronz/Spree

Answer (score 0):

use like that

`startActivityForResult(addPDFIntent, 1);`

after your done your data pick functions use return intent method

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
    resultIntent.putExtra(PrevGross,your file);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
```

below code use in main class..

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)       
    {
        if (requestCode == 1) 
        {
            prevgross = data.getExtras().getstring(your content);       
        }}}
```

} i hope this code help your app.

Comment: I mentioned that this already does not work because the request code and result code are 0. And the data is null.

Comment: store filepath name in global string in your child class ,after finish the activity,you get the file path name from that class like that:           `filename = childclass.stringname;`